# A question from the paper "Hyperbolic rigidity of higher rank lattices" by Thomas Haettel

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, lie-groups, geometric-group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry

In the paper "Hyperbolic rigidity of higher rank lattices" by Thomas Haettel, the author has made the following statement in the proof of Corollary D in page no. 18 ( https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.02004.pdf )

> "According to the proof of [DHS16, Theorem 9.15], there exists $U\in \Omega$, $U\subsetneq S$, such that some finite index subgroup $H_0$ of $H$ fixes $U$."

By [DHS16], the author has meant the [following paper (arXiv link)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.01061v2), page no. 8 by Durham-Hagen-Sisto. I could not understand how Theorem 9.15 of [DHS16] implies the above statement. Could someone explain how  Theorem 9.15 of [DHS16] implies the above statement? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't think anyone will read 18 pages + another paper just to answer how to deduce a simple corollary. The usual way these kind of deductions go - by Tits' alternative, the group is virtually free, so a f.i. subgrp is free. The way the free group is actually constructed in the proof is by ping-pong argument, hence the free group is actually fixing the relevant axis.

Answer (score 2):

Haettel is correct that the statement being used is part of the proof of the Tits alternative for HHGs.

There are more explicit references for the fact you mention.

The statement is that, if $H$ is a subgroup of an HHG $G$ and $H$ has bounded orbits in $\mathcal C(S)$, then $H$ has a finite orbit in $\mathfrak S-\{S\}$.

This follows from Proposition 9.2 in [the paper Haettel cites](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.01061.pdf): the countability hypotheses and the properness hypothesis are satisfied because of the definition of an HHG.  If $H$ has bounded orbits in $G$, it's finite, which is what Haettel is proving, so suppose not.

To apply the proposition (instead of its proof) to the subgroup $H$, the easiest thing is to replace $G$ by the *hierarchically quasiconvex hull* of $H$ (see Definition 6.1, Lemma 6.2, and Proposition 5.6 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.00632.pdf)), a sub-HHS on which $H$ still acts satisfying all the hypotheses.  This has the effect of replacing $\mathcal CS$ in the HH structure by an $H$--invariant bounded set in $\mathcal CS$, so $\partial\mathcal CS$ is now empty, and the proposition gives your conclusion.

(You don't need to do the hull thing, but if you don't, you have to instead think about the definition of the boundary of a hierarchically hyperbolic space; meanwhile, life is short.)

The proof uses some machines, though, like the aforementioned boundary, on which you find an $H$--stationary measure and use a result of Kaimanovich-Masur (the idea to use this in this sort of setting was inspired by different work by Camille Horbez, whom I think we under-credited in our paper).

Fortunately the statement you want follows much more easily from a version of the above proposition proved recently by Harry Petyt and Davide Spriano: Theorem 5.1 of [their paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.12535.pdf) yields a finite, $H$--invariant collection $\{U_1,\ldots,U_n\}\subset\mathfrak S$ such that each $\pi_{U_i}(H)$ is unbounded and any $W\in\mathfrak S$ with $\pi_W(H)$ unbounded is nested in some $U_i$.  Since $H$ has (in Haettel's situation) bounded orbits in $\mathcal C(S)$, $\pi_S(H)$ is bounded, and we conclude that each $U_i$ is properly nested in $S$.  Now pass to the finite-index subgroup of $H$ fixing all $U_i$.

The great thing about what Petyt-Spriano did is that their proof is "elementary" --- there are no boundaries involved, and if one knows the definition of an HHG, one can follow it.

(Side note: it may be that in the very last part of the induction, Haettel is inadvertently assuming that the HHG $(G,\mathfrak S)$ is *hierarchically acylindrical* --- see Definition 9.18 in [the same paper with Durham and Sisto](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.01061.pdf).  This is a natural hypothesis but does not hold for all HHGs; in fact, our original proof of 9.15 proceeded similarly and had a mistake of that type (although unrelated to the stuff above), fixed in a correction to that paper.

Haettel's inductive step certainly covers the hierarchically acylindrical case, but even if his exact argument really needs that, it seems his results combine with the corrected proof of the Tits alternative to get Corollary D in full generality.  Indeed, [the above-mentioned correction](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/geometry-and-topology/volume-24/issue-2/Correction-to-the-article-Boundaries-and-automorphisms-of-hierarchically-hyperbolic/10.2140/gt.2020.24.1051.short) shows that either $H$ is virtually abelian or there is $U\in\mathfrak S$, invariant under a finite-index subgroup of $H$, where the (virtual) action of $H$ on $\mathcal CU$ is of *general type* (this is where, as Asaf commented, we use ping-pong to find a free subgroup).  The latter case violates Haettel's Theorem A.  The former case yields an (impossible) virtual surjection to $\mathbb Z$ unless $H$ is finite.  So in any event Haettel's corollary holds as stated.)

Comment: @ Mark Hagen: Thank you very much for this detailed answer!